# TSQL: select the latest N rows, if not specified select all

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I want to get the latest N rows of a table.
Something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spProducts]
    @Rows int
AS
    SELECT TOP(50) *
    FROM tblProduct
```

But if the number of rows is not specified in the input-param `@Rows int`, all rows should be outputted (select * (all))
Do I need to implement If/Else-statements, or is there maybe a shortcut that can turn the input-param `@Rows int`into an asterix?

Comment: You will get an error if you do not supply the @Rows parameter when execute(ing) spProducts.

Comment: you can also try with this                                       CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spgetOrder]
 (@Rows int =null)
 AS
  SELECT TOP(ISNULL(@Rows,0)) * FROM AdventureWorks2008R2.dbo.Orders   
  UNION
  SELECT  * FROM AdventureWorks2008R2.dbo.Orders    WHERE @Rows is null

Comment: it seems that this does the trick. tyvm! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That works

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spProducts]
    (@Rows int =null)
AS
     SELECT TOP(ISNULL(@Rows,0)) *
     FROM tblProduct
        UNION SELECT *
    FROM tblProduct
        WHERE @Rows is null
```

Credits goes to [Naveen Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3198474/naveen-kumar), tyvm!